# remove objects from arraylist is doing strange things

Tags: arraylist, processing

In the code below, i want the balls to change from `ArrayList ballList` to another `ArrayList oldBalls` as soon as their age turns higher than a threshold value.

This code should be very simple but i can't figure out why when the age is same as the threshold (not larger) they disappear and then they come back 2 frames later.

I have checked related questions using iterators for ArrayLists in java but i think there should be a way to do this in processing without java.
Also i cant seem to post any question on the processing forum even though i can sign in, no idea why...

I have reduced the code to the minimum able to reproduce the error.

```
ArrayList <Ball> ballList;
ArrayList <Ball> oldBalls;
int threshold=4;
PFont font;

void setup(){
 size(400,400);
 frameRate(0.5);
 font=createFont("Georgia", 18);
 textFont(font);
 textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
 ballList=new ArrayList<Ball>();
 oldBalls=new ArrayList<Ball>();
 noFill();
 strokeWeight(2);
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  Ball b=new Ball(new PVector(10, random(height/10,9*height/10)),new PVector(10,0),0);
  ballList.add(b);

  stroke(0,0,200);
  for(int i=0;i<oldBalls.size();i++){
    Ball bb=oldBalls.get(i);
    bb.update();
    bb.render();
    text(bb.age,bb.pos.x,bb.pos.y);
  }

  stroke(200,0,0);
  for(int i=0;i<ballList.size();i++){
    Ball bb=ballList.get(i);
    bb.update();
    bb.render();
    bb.migrate();
    text(bb.age,bb.pos.x,bb.pos.y);
  }
}

class Ball{
  PVector pos;
  PVector vel;
  int age;

  Ball(PVector _pos, PVector _vel, int _age){
    pos=_pos;
    vel=_vel;
    age=_age;
  }

  void migrate(){
    if(age>threshold){
      oldBalls.add(this);
      ballList.remove(this);
    }
  }

  void update(){
    pos.add(vel);
    age+=1;
  }

  void render(){
    ellipse(pos.x,pos.y,24,24);
  }
}
```

Note how balls labelled with age=threshold suddenly disappear...

Comment: This doesn't seem like valid java code at all, it's not even in a class. Are the lists static? Is the Ball class an inner class? Where do you call the setup?

Comment: @Mackiavelli Note the tags. It's [tag:processing], which is based on Java.

Comment: processing is like a simplified java... its not exactly the same, though any pure java you write on processing will work perfectly fine

Comment: because i want to move objects from one list to another, thats the whole thing im trying to do

Comment: @fartagaintuxedo I don't see the behavior you're describing. What exactly do you mean when you say they disappear? Can you remove the randomness from your sketch so you can guarantee it always happens? You should only need one ball to demonstrate the problem, right?

Comment: processing has a visual interface where u can run the code and see what im trying to describe in the question. And... i dont think it can work with 1 ball, or maybe yes you are right but i think its easier to see the effect in a continuous flow - perhaps?

Comment: And the randomness only affects the position of the balls on the screen...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i guess the problem is here:

```
for(int i=0;i<ballList.size();i++){
    Ball bb=ballList.get(i);
    bb.update();
    bb.render();
    //add this
    if(bb.migrate())
        i--;
    text(bb.age,bb.pos.x,bb.pos.y);
}
```

and

```
boolean migrate(){
    if(age>threshold){
      oldBalls.add(this);
      ballList.remove(this);
      //and this
      return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

`migrate()` will remove the object from the ballList and reduce it's size by 1.

Comment: Nailed it. When you remove a ball from ballList, you skip over the following ball and never invoke text() on it.

Comment: This works, but i have never seen this code in processing... `if(bb.migrate())
        i--;`

Comment: When you `migrate()` a ball, say at index 3, it leaves the List. Then ball #4 becomes ball #3 (because it fills in the space left when the original ball #3 migrated). This code subtracts one from `i` when that happens--i changes from 3 to 2--so when you go through the `for` loop again you can look at the new ball #3.

Comment: @fartagaintuxedo what do you mean by "never seen this code"? it's java, you simply need to adjust the counter.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation...
Regarding the code, is it the same `if(bb.migrate()){
        i--;
    }` and what you have written `if(bb.migrate())
        i--;`? I had no idea i could skip the curly brackets..!

Comment: @fartagaintuxedo yes of course. if you don't use {} only the next statement belongs to `if`. I'm glad you learned something new:)

Comment: nice... learnt something new, and i also didnt know that i could adjust the iterator in a loop

Answer (score 1):

What it looks like is happening here is because you're altering the List's whilst iterating through them. Consider this for loop you have here

```
  for(int i=0;i<ballList.size();i++){
    Ball bb=ballList.get(i);
    bb.update();
    bb.render();
    bb.migrate();
    text(bb.age,bb.pos.x,bb.pos.y);
  }
```

Say ballList has 2 balls in it both age 3, the first loops gets ball[0] and then removes it from the list, i will increment and the loop will immediately exit because ballList.size() is now 1. So it's not the ball which gets to age 4 that vanishes but the subsequent one.

Comment: This will throw a ConcurrentModificationException. You can't modify a list while iterating over it.

Comment: you can't remove object on a List you are iterating on, you will get an `Exception`

Comment: Doing this causes a ConcurrentModificationException. Can't modify the List while iterating over it.

Comment: Wow, everybody jumped all over that, eh?

Comment: I was thinking ConcurrentModificationException as I was typing that so I've got no idea why I did, I'll remove it.